# usort sorting multiple fields boolean and number

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

My main array is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [active] => true
        [age] => 15
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [active] => false
        [age] => 10 
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [active] => false
        [age] => 31 
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [active] => true
        [age] => 45
    )
)
```

I need to sort the array using function usort as follows:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [active] => true
        [age] => 15
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [active] => true
        [age] => 45
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [active] => false
        [age] => 10
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [active] => false
        [age] => 45
    )
)
```

In function usort , I want to have both sorts based on "active" AND "age"

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried, show us the code you are having a problem with

Comment: I could not work with function usort!

Comment: Could be worth showing the code you have tried, may be a simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this answer will satisfied you

```
$cmp = function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['active'] == $b['active']) {
        return $a['age'] < $b['age'] ? -1 : 1;
    } else if ($a['active'] == true) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};

usort($arr, $cmp);
```

Comment: Since when can you assign a function to a varibale in php? `$cmp = function ($a, $b)`

Comment: @AltimusPrime its called anonymouse function in php, this is the page related with it https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @Hossein im sorry, ive updated the answer